# How to calculate offset for years, months, days, etc. in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, offset

We use a Retail Calendar (445) which is different from the regular one. The year begins in October and the first day of every month is not the real first day of this month. For example for this fiscal year (2020), November begins on Oct. 6th and ends on Nov. 2d, next year there will be a different dates.

I need to create an offset field/s calculating the differences between two points of times based on that calendar.

For example, if today is Dec. 3d, the data should be like this:

[image]

The calculation should be dynamic and comparing every time between the date of today and the second (past/ future/ present date).

I used many kinds of script, but no one of them works with that kind of calendar. Here is one of code examples (we use T-SQL database):

```
case 
   when Cal.FiscalYear = year(getdate()) 
      then 0
   when Cal.FiscalYear < year(getdate()) 
      then (Cal.FiscalYear - year(getdate())) 
   else (Cal.FiscalYear - year(getdate())) 
end as CurrFiscalYearOffset
```

[Here is the part of the existing calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7MMU.png)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant. E.g. `getdate()` is a product specific function.)

Comment: Hey, sample data is great, but not as a comment. Edit the question instead.

Comment: Steve, I have my "445 calendar" and know when every month begins and ending as well as the year, so I don't need to calculate the calendar itself.. 445 means the months will have 4,4 and 5 weeks in them, for example, October will contain 4 weeks, November - 4 weeks, December 5 weeks, Jan.- 4, Feb -4, March -5, etc.
My problem is to calculate this Offset. I did it successful for the regular calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Using the data you provided, this will get you most of the way there. As far as your Fiscal Calendar dilemma, in order to know how to handle other dates, your Fiscal Year calendar will need to be defined.

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = GETDATE();

DECLARE @FiscalYear TABLE
(
    FiscalYear  INT
    ,StartDate  DATE
    ,EndDate    DATE
)
INSERT INTO @FiscalYear (FiscalYear,StartDate,EndDate)
SELECT  2020,'10/6/2019','11/2/2020'

SELECT  t.dDate
        ,DATEDIFF(DAY, @Date, t.dDate) AS CurDayOffset
        ,DATEDIFF(WEEK, @Date, t.dDate) AS CurWeekOffset
        ,DATEDIFF(MONTH, @Date, t.dDate) AS CurMonthOffset
        ,CASE 
            WHEN @Date BETWEEN fy.StartDate AND fy.EndDate THEN 0
        END AS FiscalYearOffset
FROM    (
            SELECT  '10/8/2018' AS dDate
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  '12/3/2019'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  '12/4/2019'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  '10/2/2020'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  '10/5/2020'
    ) AS t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @FiscalYear AS fy ON t.dDate BETWEEN fy.StartDate AND fy.EndDate;
```

Comment: here is my calendar:

Comment: Clarifying Sam's comment: his question was edited to include a link to a picture of his 445 calendar.